# Error Uploading a document

Tags: workflow, document

When I upload a document I am getting:

> Sorry, something went wrong The file Engineering Documents 2/IPSPD2013
>   Feed Back2.jpg has been modified by i:0#.w|dataoncloud\order_123456789
>   on 07 Dec 2015 02:11:10 -0800.

This only happens when I have a workflow turned on to run automatically when a file is created.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by adding an If Statement which would Pause the workflow and then also an else section also.

Seemed to work fine.